# Around Plugin Unit Testing

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

I need help modelling a unit test class for my around plugin for graphql resolver method.
The plugin intercept error messages so that we can customize.

**namespace...applyCouponToCartplugin.php**

```
    class ApplyCouponToCartPlugin
{
    public function __construct(CouponValidator $couponValidator, ConfigData $configData) {
        $this->_couponValidator = $couponValidator;
        $this->_configData = $configData;
    }

    public function aroundResolve(ApplyCouponToCart $subject, Closure $proceed, Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, $value, $inputData) {
        $result = false;
        try {
            $result = $proceed($field, $context, $info, array($inputData['input']['coupon_code']), $inputData);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_configData->isEnabled()) {
                $msg = $this->_couponValidator->validate($inputData['input']['coupon_code'], $inputData['input']['cart_id'],$context);
                if (!empty($msg)) {
                    throw new GraphQlInputException(__($msg));
                }
            }
            throw $e;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

- After reading magento docs, and stack cant find solid examples to guide me where use cases for **aroundplugin** for unit tests

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what `$couponValidator` and `$configData` does, but let's say these are the classes for it:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CouponValidator
{
    const COUPON_CODE = 'TESTCOUP';
    const EXPIRED_MESSAGE = 'TESTCOUP has expired.';
    
    public function validate($couponCode, $cartId, $context){
        if ($couponCode  == self::COUPON_CODE){
            return self::EXPIRED_MESSAGE;
        }
    }
}

class ConfigData
{
    public function isEnabled(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then a unit test for your around plugin may look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Test\Unit\Plugin;

use Vendor\Module\Plugin\ApplyCouponToCartPlugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\Context;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextExtension;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\ApplyCouponToCart;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

use Vendor\Module\Plugin\CouponValidator;
use Vendor\Module\Plugin\ConfigData;

class ApplyCouponToCartPluginTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $plugin;
    protected $resolver;
    
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);
        
        $couponValidator = new CouponValidator();
        $configData = new ConfigData();
        
        $this->plugin = $this->objectManager->getObject(ApplyCouponToCartPlugin::class, [
            'couponValidator' => $couponValidator,
            'configData' => $configData,
        ]);
    }
    
    public function testAroundResolve() : void
    {
        $couponCode = CouponValidator::COUPON_CODE;
        $field = $this->objectManager->getObject(Field::class, [
            'name' => 'applyCouponToCart',
            'type' => 'ApplyCouponToCartOutput',
            'required' => false,
            'isList' => false
        ]);
        
        $context = $this->createMock(Context::class);
        $context->method('getUserId')->willReturn(1);
        $extensionAttributes = $this->objectManager->getObject(ContextExtension::class, []);
        $store = $this->objectManager->getObject(Store::class, []);
        $store->setStoreId(1);
        $extensionAttributes->setStore($store);
        $context->method('getExtensionAttributes')->willReturn($extensionAttributes);
        
        $info = $this->createMock(ResolveInfo::class);
        $value = [$couponCode];
        $args = [
            'input' => [
                'cart_id' => 'Ew3n4lL7PelSva0SVgjKLXRz5gV6LSVs',
                'coupon_code' => $couponCode
            ]
        ];

        $couponManagement = $this->createMock(CouponManagementInterface::class);
        $couponManagement->method('set')->willReturnCallback(function($cartId, $couponCode){
            if ($couponCode == CouponValidator::COUPON_CODE){
                throw new LocalizedException(__("The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."));
            }
        });
        
        $this->resolver = $this->objectManager->getObject(ApplyCouponToCart::class, [
            'couponManagement' => $couponManagement,
        ]);
        
        $proceed = function($field, $context, $info, $value, $args){
            return $this->resolver->resolve($field, $context, $info, $value, $args);
        };
        
        try {
            $result = $this->plugin->aroundResolve($this->resolver, $proceed, $field, $context, $info, $value, $args);
            $this->assertIsArray($result);
            
        }catch (GraphQlInputException $e){
            $expected = CouponValidator::EXPIRED_MESSAGE;
            $actual = $e->getMessage();
            $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
        }
        
        $couponCode = 'VALIDCOUP';
        $value = [$couponCode];
        $args['input']['coupon_code'] = $couponCode;
        
        $result = $this->plugin->aroundResolve($this->resolver, $proceed, $field, $context, $info, $value, $args);
        $this->assertIsArray($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, will test and adise.